# How to dynamically update configuration property in YAML file using node.js application

Tags: node.js, yaml, node-modules, apigee, azure-webapps

I want to update the attribute dynamically in YAML configuration file using node.js application. I have my secrets configured in KeyVault and it has been referenced in App Service configuration. I want to update those secrets in YAML file through node.js application.

I tried below option in YAML file, but it's not working.

```
#{process.env.password}
```

My YAML structure looks like,

```
targets:
  - host:
    ssl:
      client:
        password: XXXXXXXXXX (I want to update this password attribute using environment variables)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to do something like this

```
sources:
  - name: Main
    handler:
      postgraphile:
        connectionString: postgres://{env.POSTGRES_USER}:{env.POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@localhost/postgres
```